# Why is this type alias causing a compilation error (C++)?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, compilation, llvm

I'm writing an LLVM pass that renames functions amongst other things. I have this small piece of code

```
// Get function arguments
std::vector<Argument*> Arguments;
for (auto Arg = F.arg_begin(); Arg != F.arg_end(); ++Arg)
{
  Type *ArgTy = Arg->getType();

  if (ArgTy->isFloatingPointTy())
  {
    errs() << "Cannot test function: " << F.getName() << " (floating point arguments)\n";
    return false;
  }
  Arguments.push_back(Arg);
}
```

The line `Arguments.push_back(Arg)` is causing a compilation error:

`no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘llvm::ilist_iterator<llvm::ilist_detail::node_options<llvm::Argument, false, false, void>, false, false>’ to ‘llvm::Argument* const&’`.

However, in the header file `llvm/IR/Function.h` ([source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/IR/Function.h)), `arg_iterator` is declared as an alias for the type `Argument *`, and the functions `arg_begin()` and `arg_end()` called by a `Function` instance, return an `arg_iterator()` type. So why am I getting the type error? Does it have something to do with the use of the `auto` keyword?

Comment: You *do* know how to use iterators? What you get when (for example) you *dereference* an iterator?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when the iterator is of type `Argument*`, you get the pointed `Argument` as an lvalue. But the question is about why the type of `auto Arg = F.arg_begin()` is not `arg_iterator` (== `Argument*`) as declared in the header but something else. UnchartedWaters: Create a [mcve]. Your example is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of the files which you are using on your drive. If you are not using it directly from the GitHub, but maybe your files were coming somehow with the LLVM installation, check the actual files that you are building with.

The "blame" on the GitHub shows, that there was a change in the `arg_begin`/`arg_end` return types from `ArgumentListType::iterator` to `Argument *` about 4 months ago ([commit](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/2af0da9edd8181890ddf8193d16eacac3269c9b1)), so you might be building against the old version, which still has the original complex iterator type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dereference your iterator:

```
std::vector<Argument*> Arguments;
for (auto Arg = F.arg_begin(); Arg != F.arg_end(); ++Arg)
{
  auto *ArgTy = Arg->getType();

  if (ArgTy->isFloatingPointTy())
  {
    errs() << "Cannot test function: " << F.getName() << " (floating point arguments)\n";
    return false;
  }
  Arguments.push_back(*Arg);
}
```

This will only work if F stores objects such as `Argument*`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the compilation error, as possible solution is as follows

```
// Get function arguments
std::vector<Argument*> Arguments;
for (auto Arg = F.arg_begin(); Arg != F.arg_end(); ++Arg)
{
  Type *ArgTy = Arg->getType();

  if (ArgTy->isFloatingPointTy())
  {
    errs() << "Cannot test function: " << F.getName() << " (floating point arguments)\n";
    return false;
  }
  // Grab a pointer to the argument reference
  Argument *ArgPtr = &*Arg;
  Arguments.push_back(ArgPtr);
}
```

My problem arose from my misunderstanding of pointers vs references in C++ (see [here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html) for further detail).

I am not sure why `arg_iterator != Argument *` at compile time - it is 
perhaps because of some LLVM specific functionality. In any case, we need to dereference `Arg` in order to obtain an `Argument` type, and then take the address of the `Argument` type (with the `&` operator) in order to obtain a pointer to this `Argument` type.

Comment: I think your confusion is between iterators and pointers, not references and pointers

Comment: The code should work in the original version as well, but only if the `arg_begin` return type really is `Argument *`, i.e. if you are using the recent version from GitHub - there was a change, see my answer.